# Number Array Type Not Interpreted an Array?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

```
export class ... {
   single: any[] = [];
   multi: any[] = [];

   view: number[] = [700, 400];
   ... <Removed for brevity>
}
```

Error Msg: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'

I'm not really sure what this means.  I have a variable which is typed as a number array but when the "view" variable is used in the template it throws the above error.  Anyone run into this issue?

The only resolution I have found is to put the array itself--[view]=[700, 400]--in the template.  I am a bit baffled by this as it should work.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Brevity is fine but pseudocode means we can't test it.  And *where* is that error message?

Comment: Probably, whatever you want to assign `.view` to has a type of `[number, number]` (=a tuple type) which is more specific than the explicit type of `.view` (`number[]`). Check out this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqAWYAuBTAbigTtA3gKGmggEsA7AcxBQC5oxSBPAbQF1oBeaVgbgOgFsAriCTFa9Zm048+aYigDutJqUH8ARlgA00VRqxSuAdgAMJnQBYzLbtAD0d6AB4AtNGAB7TJhTAk0JHgUaBQADwAHEGJgYn8kBnDg+lIPJGRiD1JoIJ88AF88PE9SCH8yUvpgYM5SRThEVAxMAAoASl4izNLoOUVlPU1MHQGDDmhytNIqgDpehV4gA). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you.  The way the value was initialized made me think it was an array with 2 values.  When I got a peak into how @swimlane defined the "view" variable it became clear that it was defined as [number, number] and not number[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input in your template is expecting a tuple of two numbers, but you've typed *view* as a number array.  The answer is change the typing of *view* to a tuple.

```
view: [number, number] = [700, 400];
```

You can also define your own *toTuple* method to convert a number array like *view* to a tuple if necessary.

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number, R extends T[] = []> = R['length'] extends N ? R : Tuple<T, N, [T, ...R]>;
function toTuple<T, L extends number>(values: T[], length: L): Tuple<T, L> {
  if (values.length < length) {
      throw new Error('invalid values length');
  }
  return values.slice(0, length) as Tuple<T, L>;
}
```